# Calendar app widget that displays date and opens calendar

Tags: android

On my iPhone I have a Calendar icon that displays the date and opens the Calendar app.

I had something similar for Android but it appears to be removed from the Play store.

Comment: There are calendar widgets available by default with Android. Don't they do the job? AFAIR the 1x1 calendar widget does exactly that: show the current date, and open the calendar when tapped. I you don't have that (I just checked the only device with stock Android I have and it's not there): what size should it be? What details should it show? You can find some calendar widgets [here in my list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_widgets) by the way.

Comment: @Izzy calendar widget 2 lite used to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be tons of options under the option "Day Widget" under the play store.

This is the one I am currently using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.o172.DayWidget